# Check a variable within a range with a binary variable

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint-satisfaction

I have a value, a, it can be any value from 0 to 1. In an integer linear program, how can I formulate a constraint that uses a binary variable, y, to determine whether a is within a range of 0 and 1 or not.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  You say x can be any value from 0 to 1; if so, you already know that a is in that range -- there is nothing to determine.  Please edit the question to explain more clearly what you're trying to do.  Thank you!

Comment: "it can be any value from 0 to 1", shouldn't a variable in an **integer** linear program only have integer values?

Comment: @D.W. I think the point is that, in valid solutions, the value of the variable is in $[0,1]$ and the asker wants constraints that ensure it really is in that range. But, still, with an integer linear program, the variable's value is either $0$ or $1$, so I'm not sure what's really going on, here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand corectly, you want to formulate a system of linear constraints on a real variable $a$ and a $\{0,1\}$-variable $y$ 
such that the solutions are given by
$$[0,1]\times\{1\} \bigcup [1,\infty)\times \{0\}.$$

This is impossible.  No linear constraint can put an upper bound on $a$ for some values of $y$ without putting an upper bound on $a$ for *all* values of $y$.

You can, however, just split the problem into two pieces and solve each one separately.